# What will happen if a timer object is due start at a calendar time and Matlab is busy?

Tags: matlab, timer

What will happen if a timer object is due start at a calendar time and Matlab is busy? Will Matlab execute `TimerFcn` after the current task is finished or will there be parallel execution or alternating execution?

For example,

```
t=timer;

t.TimerFcn=@(~,~)disp(clock);

[Y, M, D, H, MI, S] = datevec(now+0.02);

startat(t,Y,M,D,H,MI,S);
```

what will happen if Matlab is busy in 0.02 days from now?

Comment: Interesting question. Of course, you could do the experiment... // MATLAB has no concurrent execution AFAIK. It could pause the current task to run the timer object, or it could delay running the timer object.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I've found Matlab running `TimerFcn` in the background -- visually. I've only tried when I actually need `TimerFcn` to be running. So I've been afraid of interrupting it. I should try a trivial `TimerFcn` to see how it interacts with other things. I wonder for more demanding functions, whether Matlab would alternate between the input commands or even get a second thread. For now, maybe someone else has had experience with this.

Comment: Argyll, I see what you worry about. See the edit to my answer. There's no concurrency and no interleaving of different functions. The main thread is interrupted and the timer object gets the reins for as long as it needs.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Nice test. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like MATLAB will pause the currently executing code to run the timer object:

```matlab
t = timer;
t.TimerFcn = @timer_func;
onesecond = 1/(24*60*60); % days
[Y, M, D, H, MI, S] = datevec(now + 5 * onesecond);
startat(t,Y,M,D,H,MI,S);

disp(datetime('now'))

for ii=1:1000
   if mod(ii,100)==0
      disp('main thread working...')
   end
   a = atan2(rand(1e6,1),rand(1e6,1));
end

function timer_func(~,~)
disp(datetime('now'))
for ii=1:1000
   if mod(ii,100)==0
      disp('timer_func working...')
   end
   a = atan2(rand(1e6,1),rand(1e6,1));
end
end
```

This outputs:

```
   10-Aug-2020 23:53:24

main thread working...
main thread working...
   10-Aug-2020 23:53:29

timer_func working...
timer_func working...
timer_func working...
timer_func working...
timer_func working...
timer_func working...
timer_func working...
timer_func working...
timer_func working...
timer_func working...
main thread working...
main thread working...
main thread working...
main thread working...
main thread working...
main thread working...
main thread working...
main thread working...
```